# Batch glimpse sensor with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement glimpse sensor from Recurrent models of visual attention paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6247).

Basically, I need to extract a rectangular crop from 2d numpy array. There is no problem doing it for a single input, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with batches.

So the inputs are:

- Images - samples x height x width array
- Locations - samples x 2 array - set of x,y coordinates for each sample image

The output should be a per sample crop area of some size (for example 100x100), where the top-left corner of the crop is specified by the corresponding location entry, so it should be samples x 100 x 100. For now I'm ignoring all the corner cases, so it can be assumed that the crop is completely contained inside the image and that the locations are already in the format usable for numpy indexing.

In the case of a single image the task is easy:

```
image[location[0]:location[0]+100, location[1]:location[1]+100]
```

but applying it to batches it somewhat harder. Doing

```
image[:, location[:,0]:location[:,0]+100, location[:,1]:location[:,1]+100]
```

doesn't work, because slices don't accept numpy arrays.

Supplying full set of indices for arbitrary crop size didn't seem to work for me either.

Another option is to just loop through the batch and extract the crop from each image individually, but I'm not sure how efficient this will be.

So, is this sort of indexing possible in numpy without the use of loops?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work: I simply supplied the full set of indices, as you specified above. We can simply generate the ranges first:

```
ranges_x = [list(range(i, i+10)) for i, _ in locations]
ranges_y = [list(range(j, j+10)) for _, j in locations]
```

Then, just apply these indices:

```
images[:, ranges_x, ranges_y]
```

Here's a toy example that I tried:

```
>>> images = np.random.random(size=(10, 100, 100))
>>> images[0].shape
(100, 100)
>>> locations = np.random.random_integers(0, 25, size=(10, 2))
>>> ranges_x = [list(range(i, i+10)) for i, _ in locations]
>>> ranges_y = [list(range(j, j+10)) for _, j in locations]
>>> crops = images[:, ranges_x, ranges_y]
>>> crops[0].shape
(10, 10)
>>> locations[0]
array([16,  1])
>>> images[0][16][1]
0.078065688223271312
>>> crops[0][0][0]
0.078065688223271312
```

Comment: The shape is correct, but `crops` are not crops out of the given image. You can easily check this by initializing `images` with `numpy.arange(10*100*100).reshape(10, 100, 100)` and looking at `crops[0]`.